# Get last folder name from URL path , getJSON Api , in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to get last folder name from URL path 000000

**URL path :**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/#/000000
```

**Html code :**

```
<html>

<body>
  <p id="link"></p>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var aaa = "https://www.example.com/";
var bbb = "last folder name from URL path";
$.getJSON(aaa+bbb, function(data) {
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = data.url;
});

alert(aaa+bbb);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**I want the result like this :**

```
$.getJSON("https://www.example.com/000000", function(data)
alert(https://www.example.com/000000)
```

Comment: By "folder name" do you mean `"000000"`?

Comment: Yes Sir , "000000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aaa = "https://www.example.com/";
var bbb = document.location.href.split("#/");
$.getJSON(aaa+bbb[1], function(data) {
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = data.url;
});

alert(aaa+bbb[1]);
```

Comment: Than you VERY MUCH :)  Young Kyun Jin

Comment: @fawzikls It's my pleasure :)